Blockchain.com has frozen my Atomic wallet
I have been investing money into Bitcoin for almost a year now. I decided it was time to get some back. I use the Blantomic platform and asked them to send an amount to my Atomic wallet. I do not have a blockchain.com account. Shortly after they sent the amount I received an email from Blockchain-compliance.com saying I need to send 20% of the amount to verify and make my account liquid. After that it was to pay taxes. I am not sure if this is a scam and I am out of money. Does this sound like a scam or am I paranoid.

See: Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal? Yes, it is definitely a scam.
